# How to change the contours and legend in mathematica contour plot?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

The ContourPlot function in *Mathematica* automatically gets you a legend and contours with colors on the plot which are uniformly distributed ( for example, blue color from 0.1 to 0.2 function values, green from 0.2 to 0.3 and etc.) In my case, function, that I plot, has a large number of values in the 0.1 to 0.2 and only few from 0.2 to 1. If I want to distinguish better values from 0.1 to 0.2 and make several colors for this section, and make the values from 0.2 to 1 by one color, how should I do this?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the *Mathematica* function `Hue[z]` to assign a color to your contours. To do this, you're going to use the option `ColorFunction`, like this:

```
ContourPlot[myFunction, {x,-10,10}, {y,-10,10}, ColorFunction -> Function[{f},Hue[g[f]]]]
```

In this code, `g[f]` is some function that maps the contour level to a hue (a value between 1 and 255). You said you wanted many values between 0 and 0.2, and only a few between 0.2 and 1, so I would use something like

```
g[f_] := 100*(5*f)^(1/4)
```

Obviously you can change this to fit. If this doesn't help, you may need to increase the number of contours, using the option `Contours->n`, where n is how many you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, I played around with it some more. You might want to use a function more like `g = 100*e^(-10*f)`